# Java: Creating a Star from Circle Created Polygon

Tags: java, loops, drawing, polygons

I'm having trouble creating the spikiness (to turn the circle created via polygon into a star). Basically I want to add points out of the circle to turn it into a star. It is an assignment for a course. I don't know how to go about creating the code for the spikiness.

Notes:

1. The spikiness parameter can range from 0.0 to 1.0 with 0.0 being not spikey (like a soccer ball) and 1.0 being extremely spikey (like a sea urchin).
2. The spikiness parameter determines the radius of the inner circle using the formula: innerRadius = radius * (1.0 - spikiness) (An example formula I tried implementing but with no success)

I'd appreciate the help!

My code:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class StarSampler {

       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
           DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(500, 500);
           Graphics2D g = panel.getGraphics();
           g.setColor(Color.BLUE);

           fillStar(g, 250, 250, 100, 36, 1); // The (1) is for extreme spikeness
       }

       public static void fillStar(Graphics2D g, int ctrX, int ctrY, int radius, int nPoints, double spikiness)
       {
           double xDouble[] = new double[nPoints];
           double yDouble[] = new double [nPoints];

           int xPoint[] = new int[nPoints];
           int yPoint[]= new int[nPoints];

           int angle = 0;

           for (int i = 0; i < nPoints; i++) // Continue through use of Prog6 formula
           {
               xDouble[i] = ctrX  + radius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle));
               yDouble[i] = ctrY + radius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle));
               angle += 10;
           }
           for (int j = 0; j < nPoints; j++) // Casts for ints and doubles
           {
               xPoint[j] = (int) xDouble[j];
               yPoint[j] = (int) yDouble[j];
           }
           g.fillPolygon(xPoint, yPoint, nPoints); // Creates polygon
       }
}
```

Comment: A star with N "points" is just a circle with 2N points, where points 0, 2, 4... are at radius `R`, and points 1, 3, 4... are at radius `spikiness * R`. You're only creating `N` points (not `2N`), and you're not using `spikiness`.

Comment: I know I'm not creating 2N, and I'm not using spikiness. Would I basically just copy the entire method over and then do the spikiness?

Answer (score 0):

A star with N "points" is just a circle with 2N points, where points 0, 2, 4... are at radius `R`, and points 1, 3, 5... are at radius `spikiness * R`.

You're only creating `N` points (not `2N`), and you're not using `spikiness`. Something like this might work (untested):

```
double xDouble[] = new double[2*nPoints];
double yDouble[] = new double[2*nPoints];

for (int i = 0; i < 2*nPoints; i++)
{
  double iRadius = (i % 2 == 0) ? radius : (radius * spikiness);
  double angle = i * 360.0 / (2*nPoints);

  xDouble[i] = ctrX + iRadius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle));
  yDouble[i] = ctrY + iRadius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle));
}
```

Comment: I'm stumped on getting the program to draw the polygon drawPolygon(int, int, int), I tried casting too.